# Different loss functions for estimation and cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, estimation, inference, goodness-of-fit, loss-functions

Assume that the goal is to estimate some parameter $\theta$ (finite or infinite dimensional) based on some data available. Also, assume that there are other nuisance parameters are present in the model (for example, smoothing parameter or penalisation constant etc.)

The question: in which cases it makes sense (or even important and recommended) to use one loss-function for estimation of the parameter $\theta$ and another one for cross-validating of other nuisance parameters or checking goodness of fit?

Comment: If you're checking goodness of fit, you'll almost certainly be using a different evaluation function than you will for estimation of the parameter; the former might be, for example, based on the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) but the latter might be based on maximizing the likelihood function.

Comment: Dear @jbowman, good point! For goodness of fit it is clear, but what could you say about, for example, penalised estimators?